# Is using ServiceBus required when my SignalR app will be deployed to WindowsAzure?

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-web-app-service, signalr-hub

I created a simple tic tac toe game, which is a web app that calls the SignalR Hub inside the same application. When deploying to a shared hosting environment it works as charm but when deploying to WindowsAzure, the response time of the Hub is relly long, and I even don't get response sometimes until I make a second call to the Hub

I guess is something that I'm misunderstanding with the Azure cloud architecture; I've searched about this problem with no luck; I found that maybe I should be using ServiceBus Queue with Worker and Web roles, but this will imply changing all the behavior of my app to call the controller (which will be calling the worker role throug the service bus queue) instead of calling the hub directly from my view for getting the real time experience

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Azure Service are you using, Cloud Service (Web/Worker), Azure Web Sites (WAWS)?

There is a known SignalR bug with Web Sites: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/510

You can work around this for now by using longpolling. @dfowler might be able to assist you better..

Comment: I'm using Azure websites... So I think it is the same problem... I don't know it this is fixed on 0.5.3, but if not I'll just switch to long polling in the meanwhile... I'll give a try on this over the week and see what happens :)